# Adding a new table to existing database in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having some trouble understand how to add a new table to an existing database in my web application mvc 4. I have added the table to the database, then i added the model. When I build the solution, i get this error: The namespace 'MvcFFL.Models' already contains a definition for 'PlayerDBContext' C:\Webs\MvcFFL\MvcFFL\Models\Player.cs   19

Here is my Abbrviations model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcFFL.Models
{
    public class Abbrivations
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Abbrv { get; set; }
        public string Team { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlayerDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Abbrivations> Abbrvs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does the Dbset line need to go into the Player.cs file or is it actually needed? I would like to be able use the table to add data into

Comment: do you by any chance have one more class that is also called PlayerDBContext?

Comment: Yes I do, I understand that is the error but why when i have it referencing a different part of the DBset?

Comment: Why not just add all DbSets to a single DbContext? Is there any reason why you separated them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restructure how my EF Context was set up. Have your model classes on their own, with no mention of a context. Then have a context file with your DbContext and DbSet of your models.

I don't usually speak in absolutes, but this is objectively a better way to structure your ef than the way you are currently doing it.

```
public class PlayerDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Abbreviations> Abbrvs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams{ get; set; }
    //and any other context specific information OnModelCreating, SaveChanges, etc
}
```

Your application context should only be declared once per application, otherwise it will be extermely confusing and more likely, not work.

Comment: oh ok, I can understand that now, thanks that worked